# Woocommerce add to cart and redirect to Custom URL - Different for each link

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

So I am using a link on this page: https://www.revealio.com/make-brand-come-alive/ (yellow button).

The link is supposed to add the product to the cart and then send them to the next step in the sales funnel.

For the link URL I used:

```
https://www.revealio.com/help-creating-video?add-to-cart=4951
```

and

```
https://www.revealio.com/help-creating-video?add-to-cart=4951&quantity=1
```

Full link code is:

```
<a href="https://www.revealio.com/help-creating-video?add-to-cart=8877">YES! MAKE MY BRAND COME ALIVE!</a>
```

I found this code here: https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

If you need to see the cart (we are still redesigning these pages) you can go here in a seperate browser tab to see how it updates: https://www.revealio.com/cart/

The problem is that it is adding 2 products to my cart instead of 1.

**How can I get this to just add one of my products to the cart and move on?**

Here is something new I found out. If I just go directly to the link it only adds one product. If I click on the link in the page (https://www.revealio.com/make-brand-come-alive/) it adds 2 products. It does the same for a button or a text link.

Comment: have you made this link hard code?

Comment: I have. I had just added the code that I used originally before I put it in the button above. I just tried to create a new product and use that ID and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!

It needs a / before the ?

https://www.revealio.com/help-creating-video/?add-to-cart=4951

I was using: https://www.revealio.com/help-creating-video?add-to-cart=4951 which gave two item in the cart.

Comment: That's not the issue for me. WooCommerce is still adding not 2, but 3 products to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

Use the shortcodes provided by WooCommerce to render the add to cart links.  https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-shortcodes/

```
[add_to_cart_url id="99"]
```

Comment: That would be nice but we want them to add the product to the cart and redirect to a new page. the way to do this is to make a link like this: https://www.yoursite.com/custom-page?add-to-cart=ProdID

Comment: You can modify the redirect with filters.